# No such file or Directory, even if file present and executable

Tags: executable, 32bit

I have two machines, and I have installed the exact same packages on both machines.

On one machine everything is working perfectly fine. But on another machine, there is at least one file where its `No such file or directory`, even if it is present and executable.

I can read the contents of file also.

I know that file is of 32bit, but on another machine same 32bit binaries are working okay.

Can somebody please help.

1st machine : Working Fine

```
bash # file /sbin/vxdmpadm
/sbin/vxdmpadm: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.0.0, BuildID[sha1]=f62ed2d5a57fb9893ad2a89083c66493ce547c10, not stripped

bash # uname -a
Linux 3.12.28-4-default #1 SMP Thu Sep 25 17:02:34 UTC 2014 (9879bd4) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

bash # /sbin/vxdmpadm
VxVM vxdmpadm ERROR V-5-1-2110  Incorrect Usage # << Expected.

bash # ls -lrt /sbin/vxdmpadm
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root sys 972953 Oct 14 19:08 /sbin/vxdmpadm
```

2nd Machine - Faulty One

```
bash # file /sbin/vxdmpadm
/sbin/vxdmpadm: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.0.0, BuildID[sha1]=2d90bb5228e59b2e8de22d0b8db36fb85aeb1064, not stripped

bash # uname -a
Linux  3.12.28-4-default #1 SMP Thu Sep 25 17:02:34 UTC 2014 (9879bd4) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

bash # /sbin/vxdmpadm
bash: /sbin/vxdmpadm: No such file or directory   # << Why this is coming

bash # ls -lrt /sbin/vxdmpadm
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root sys 972953 Aug 31 08:40 /sbin/vxdmpadm
```

Comment: The build IDs are different. If you copy /sbin/vxdmpadm from the 2nd machine to, say, /var/tmp/vxdmpadm on the first machine, does it run?

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /sbin/vxdmpadm` on the non-working system? Perhaps there is a missing 32-bit library.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the command as root on the second machine?

Comment: Post the output of `ldd /sbin/vxdmpadm` on the faulty machine.

Comment: Yes, I am running as root user.

Comment: The copy from working machine isn't working on faulty one.

`bash # /vxdmpadm`

`bash: /vxdmpadm: No such file or directory`

Comment: On working machine

`# ldd /sbin/vxdmpadm 
        linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7747000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0xf76f5000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf76af000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7693000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf74e7000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7748000)`




On faulty machine 

`bash # ldd /sbin/vxdmpadm 
        not a dynamic executable`

Comment: I think its the problem with the 32 bit library which is not present on the system

Comment: See our master question on the topic. If you don't know how to install 32-bit support on your distribution, tell us what distribution it is.

Comment: The message "no such file or directory" is also caused by a missing library or other resources.

Comment: I am running this on SLES12 OS

`# uname -a`

`Linux 3.12.28-4-default #1 SMP Thu Sep 25 17:02:34 UTC 2014 (9879bd4) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I tried to find rpm for ld.so 32-bit version, but for sles12, if you have any repository online, please provide the link where i can download rpm from.